# Prometheus : Distinguish Application metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks

I am running my services on EKS clusters. In order to collect the application metrics [API response times, status and number of calls], I came across Prometheus. There are following steps that I think needs to be done:

1. Cluster role, Service account and role binding: this will allow my prometheus service to talk to the cluster nods, pods and services [defined in the resources section].
2. Configmap: this allows the scraping process and defines different roles.
3. Service and ingress: to establish the endpoints [e.g.: 9090] and routes the traffic from internet.

I came across [prometheus using helm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/prometheus.html) which describes how we can make use of helm predefined prometheus charts in order to get the raw metrics from kubernetes.

I followed the steps:

```
kubectl create namespace prometheus

helm install prometheus stable/prometheus \
    --namespace prometheus \
    --set alertmanager.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2",server.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2"

kubectl get pods -n prometheus
```

I can see the pods running with that namespace. Now, I have two questions,

1. I am having multiple services (For example, service A and service B)
   running on the cluster. So, how can I distinguish the metrics on
   Prometheus.
2. Do I need to run `kubectl --namespace=prometheus port-forward deploy/prometheus-server 9090` everytime to see the results? I see
   [targetPort](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus/templates/server-service.yaml#L37) is defined as `9090` then why do I need to run the
   command? Can I just `values.yaml` instead?

Comment: did try to follow the prometheus docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well to answer your questions

1. Yes, you can distinguish the service metrics by using label just use like this in your configMap of prometheus

   ```
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "<yourfirstservicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<yourservice1portnumber>"
        labels:
          instance: 'service1'
      - targets:
          - "<yourservice2name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<yourservice2port>"
        labels:
          instance: 'service2'
   ```
2. Yes you have to do that port-forward but if you are planning to use grafana for visualization then new grafana version provide built in query run functionality.

I hope this will help !!

Comment: 1. I am currently using the helm for prometheus. Are you telling me to write all the files? 2. Why do I need to port-forward? The service.yaml file should establish the endpoints? 3. I see under Service Discovery my services [with different namespace] are dropped. They also have the /metrics path but are dropped. What does it mean? [I have two services running on cluster and have two kubernetes-apiservers `active`]

Comment: @Amul123 No, I mean you have to edit your configMap and just add the targets part in your promethues configMap to get metrics from two different services. I have updated my answer have a look on the configMap which I have provided. and to answer your second question if you do not port-forward then how you will check what queries returning what kind of information. you have to do port-forward to check the queries and it's data